# How do you change the Krita Line Tool's line size (weight/thickness)

Tags: krita

Krita (v2.9.7) and graphics arts newbie. How do you change the "Line Tools" line size (weight/thickness)?

I've right-clicked my drawn line to "pop up" a seemingly useful set of options, e.g. pen, eraser, color, etc. but no size. Help for a newbie would be appreciated. Not finding this intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Open the "Tool Options" docker (*Settings → Dockers → Tool Options*).

Then select your line (or other vector object), in the "Tool Options" docker select the middle (line) tab, and use the "Thickness" control.

[image]

---

*Notes:*

1. You didn't right-click your *drawn line*, you right-clicked the *canvas* (i.e. the mouse position of right-clicking doesn't matter).
2. Your Krita version is pretty old, consider updating it to the current one (4.4.2 nowadays).

Comment: I am struggling with my Krita update and I can't verify your answer at this time. Unfortunately this is a low priority task so it may take me some time to resolve my Krita update issues and verify you answer. However, I'll endeavor not to forget and to confirm your answer when I am able.

Comment: I've abandoned Krita but credited you for your answer. It seems sound. I learned to do what I needed with GIMP. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottWelker, nice from you.